# Can I save timeshift snapshot to dropbox?

Tags: backup, dropbox

My timeshift snapshots were taking up too much space on my laptop. Is it possible to move the snapshot from /home/timeshift to my dropbox folder to save space?

And then restore by moving the snapshot back into the /home/timeshift directory?

Comment: What is timeshift snapshot??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never got a response, so here I am to save the day, two years later.

Nope. Timeshift seems to target partitions when looking for backup locations. Dropbox is a folder in your *nix partition. I'd just recommend getting an external hard drive or SSD for making future timeshift backups.

I wish they allowed backups to directories in partitions. That would be nice.